# XML Import into Access needs a Foreign key

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I'm trying to import multiple XML files into Access and using a transform.  I need the foreign key OrderID to show up on the Program table.
Here is my XML:

```
<Requests>
<Request>
<orderID>12345</orderID>
<FA><![CDATA[Jon Smith]]></FA>
<FA_state>MN</FA_state>
<ship_to>Online Delivery</ship_to>
<prospect><![CDATA[Elvis]]></prospect>
<address><![CDATA[2999 Street]]></address>
<city><![CDATA[Minneapolis]]></city>
<state>MN</state>
<zip>55413</zip>
<ship_dt>10/16/2015 11:45:11</ship_dt>
<delivery_method>Online Delivery</delivery_method>
<programs>
  <program>
    <program_name><![CDATA[Hedge Fund]></program_name>
    <copy_number>56211B87IUQPTCE</copy_number>
  </program>
</programs>
 <file_create_dt>10/16/2015</file_create_dt>
<request_dt>10/15/2015 09:19:50</request_dt>
<employee_id>1102132</employee_id>
</Request>
</Requests>
```

And the transform I am using:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="program">
    <program>
        <orderID><xsl:value-of select="../orderID"/></orderID>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </program>
</xsl:template>
```

The transform creates the foreign key field on the Program table, but fails to insert any values.  I'm totally perplexed at this point.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template matches the `program` node, so the XPath expression `../OrderID` will select the `OrderID` element that is a child of the parent of the current `program` node. But the `OrderID` is a child of the "grandparent".

You should try this, to go back up one extra level

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../orderID"/>
```